# Adding a ribbon button using the object model

Tags: ribbon

I'm trying to register a custom action on a site collection that adds a button to the SharePoint ribbon. I want to do this using the object model and not declaratively in XML. Does anyone know of this is even possible? I've been looking at SPRibbonButton but cannot figure a way to achieve this.

Comment: @orl78: Remember to mark questions as answered if you have an answer that works for you. This rewards those that help you out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [SPRibbon.RegisterDataExtension()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.commandui.ribbon.registerdataextension.aspx) to insert Ribbon stuff. You're inserting XML though through this method.

Comment: Thanks Wictor, yeah I had seen this method and thought it may be the solution. I was hoping though that there may be a way to set properties on an spribbonbutton object and then call .add() or similar. Thx again

Answer (score 1):

The following links to an example using the RegisterDataExtension() method

[Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Web Part with a Contextual Tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407578.aspx)