# Adding functionality to Ribbon 

Tags: ribbon

In SharePoint 2010 when adding a link to a site/page I am able to set a number of properties.  I'd like to be able to add a "no-follow" attribute so that users can easily select whether the link should be followed or not by a search engine spider.

I've seen how to [add a button to the ribbon](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5102/adding-a-ribbon-button-using-the-object-model), just wondering if this is the way to add to the link tools tab?

If you look at the link tools tab you will see there is a "open in new window" checkbox for the link, I'd like to add a "No Follow" checkbox for the link that adds the no follow attribute to the markup.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong: 
Using a ribbon button, you want to add a "no-follow" attribute to a selected link?

Comment: Correct, in much the same way as you have a checkbox for "open in new window"

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? If so, can you please provide the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to add your checkbox here -

- Group ID: `Ribbon.Link.Link.Behavior`
- Controls ID: `Ribbon.Link.Link.Behavior.Controls`

I found this from investigating the out-of-the-box ribbon buttons that are all defined in this file:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML